# How if MJPEG frame rate defined in the file?

Tags: mjpeg

Looks like MJPEG is "just a sequence of the compressed JPEG images". If they are served real time from the server, the frame rate probably can be defined by the streaming speed. But if it is a .mjpeg file in the filesystem, who defines the frame rate? Or is it so that this format cannot be represented in a form of the file and can only be a server-side stream?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not defined. If such file must be played locally (for debug purposes, etc), it can be converted with ffmpeg that can assume any transfer rate via bitrate switch (-b).

```
ffmpeg -i source_file.mjpeg -b 4000k -vcodec libx264 destination_file.mp4
```

The produced file then can be played the way it would appear as coming from the server:

```
cvlc destination_file.mp4
```